# What is the best way in jQuery instead of setInterval?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, livechat

I have a chat application and I've used `setInterval()` where the user get chat messages every 2 seconds. What's the best way to improve this chat application instead of using `setInterval()`? How can we `listen` while there is no event by user to get messages?

I searched and found something about `socket programming`. But I want to use jQuery.

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Use sockets for message transport. It has nothing to do with jQuery, it's just DOM library.

Comment: you can use websocket in javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Serversend event which helped to ur question

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_serversentevents.asp

Comment: Thanks a lot, and how can we use this in jQuery library?

Answer (score 1):

You can use websockets with jQuery too. [Socket.io](http://socket.io/) is great library that provides API for working with websockets. They are doing different work by themselves, jQuery helps you with DOM and provide other coding utils like promises, ajax polyfills and so on. Socket.io provides you websocket API and polyfills for old browsers that do not support it.

Here is [small tutorial](http://socket.io/get-started/chat/) of creating simple chat application with sockets.io and node.js backend.